# Getting a buildable Boost extract with bcp

Tags: c++, boost, bcp, bjam

I'm using bcp to extract Boost.Archive from Boost. Unfortunately I can't build this extract. Boost.Archive is not a header-only library.

bjam complains

```
Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam"
```

Is there any way to tell bcp to make the extract buildable with bjam (copy boost-build.jam to the right place)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place would be any parent directory of the directory where you have extracted Boost.Archive (or that directory itself). That file shall contain a single line:

```
boost-build /path/to/boost/tools/build/v2 ;
```

where /path/to/boost needs to be substituted appropriately. This file tells bjam (the low level build engine) where to load Boost.Build build system from.
Then cd to libs/archive/build, and invoke bjam from there. That would build just the Archive library.